# C# - An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, object, include

So I have two functions and I'm getting an interesting problem. Essentially I'm aiming to make my code more portable in an easily includeable cs file.

Here's said cs file:

```
namespace basicFunctions {
public partial class phpPort : System.Web.UI.Page {
    public string includer(string filename) {
        string path = Server.MapPath("./" + filename);
        string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
        return content;
    }
    public void returnError() {
        Response.Write("<h2>An error has occurred!</h2>");
        Response.Write("<p>You have followed an incorrect link. Please double check and try again.</p>");
        Response.Write(includer("footer.html"));
        Response.End();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the page that is referencing it:

```
<% @Page Language="C#" Debug="true" Inherits="basicFunctions.phpPort" CodeFile="basicfunctions.cs" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.Web.Configuration" %>

<script language="C#" runat="server">
void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e) {
    Response.Write(basicFunctions.phpPort.includer("header.html"));
    //irrelevant code
    if ('stuff happens') {
        basicFunctions.phpPort.returnError();
    }
    Response.Write(basicFunctions.phpPort.includer("footer.html"));
}
</script>
```

The error I'm getting is the one listed above, namely:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'basicFunctions.phpPort.includer(string)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an instance of your `phpPort` class as it and all the methods you have defined on it are not static.

Since you are on the `aspx` page that *inherits* from this class, when it loads it already *is* an instance of the class and you can call the methods on it directly.

You need to modify your code to use the functions directly:

```
void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e) {
    Response.Write(includer("header.html"));
    //irrelevant code
    if ('stuff happens') {
        returnError();
    }
    Response.Write(includer("footer.html"));
}
```

Comment: The OP has an instance- `this`

Comment: basicFunction seems namespace in this case.

Comment: This has fixed it (I'll mark it correct when it allows me to). Now I'm having the issue of `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Server.get'` on Server.MapPath. Any ideas?

Comment: @user798080 - From what I can see, that should simply work (since your class inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page`).

Comment: I made a new page for the new code and error [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505187/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method-or-property-s[/link]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call basicFunctions.phpPort.includer as a static method you need the static keyword on it as follows:

```
public static void returnError
public static string includer
```

If you're not doing a static call, your base page needs to call from "this"

```
if ('stuff happens') {
    this.returnError();
}
```